# Related DropDowns option deletion using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdowns DD1 & DD2 , I want that if user selects option HELLO (value="100") in DD1  and presses a key , then the same value option in DD2 is removed,  DD1 will have that option,
it would only be removed from DD2

```
var selectedItems = $('#DD1').val();


 for ( var i = 0 ; i < selectedItems.length; i++) 
        {
           $("#DD2 option[value='"+selectedItems[i]+']"').remove();
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code. Which keyboard key are they going to be pressing?

Comment: @Treffynnon :any key sir, lets take it as 9

Answer (score 0):

This does not handle the keypress event, but this is what could go in the callback when you figure out the specifics of the event you want to listen for.

```
var dd1 = $("#DD1").val();

$("option[value='"+dd1+"']", $("#DD2")).detach();
```

Comment: sir, the ids are DD1 and DD2 , so in place of  $(DD1-Selector-Here).val() ,  I would have to write  $('#DD1').val(); i guess ?

Comment: sir, i have posted what i was doing

Answer (score 0):

Mine is working now ;

```
$('#DD1').bind('keypress', function(e) { 

if ( e.which == 19)

{ 
var selectedItems = $('#DD1').val();


 for ( var i = 0 ; i < selectedItems.length; i++) 
        {
           $("#DD2 option[value='"+selectedItems[i]+"']").remove();
        } 
}  
 }
```

Comment: So you're checking for the "Pause/Break" Key to be down, because e.which == 19 is the "Pause/Break" key on most "Standard" keyboards (tested on several different keyboards including dell package and gateway package kb's). Just trying to clarify what you are doing and its function so maybe i could help in a shorter code manner. (see my which list here -> http://forum.jquery.com/topic/eventwhich-code-list-just-for-help)

Comment: uhm, I program on 3 different systems (basically for cross-checking and bencchmarking) and I just checked, using a simple fiddle form I have and got the same as I always have, 19=Puase and 13=Enter.

Comment: @SpYk3HH is correct, 13 is the keycode for enter...more importantly, why would you require a keypress?  Is the user going to find the selection they want and then press enter?  That is not usually how a dropdown is used.  Why not just listen for the change event?